# Is it possible to hide Blog tools links based on permission level?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to hide Blog tools links based on permission level? I want those link should not be appear for others except admins.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit blog tools web parts and select audience setting.
[image]

Comment: I want to hide some specific link for specific group or users. Say,  I want to hide other links except "Create a post". Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: According to my research, we can't set permissions for specific links.Thank you for your understanding.